# Can I create only one static instance of DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Is it possible to create only one static instance of `DateTimeFormatter` and use it everywhere in my project, instead of creating it multiple times?

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Can there be thread-safety issues in such cases?

Comment: as per the javadocs this class is immutable and thread safe so should be ok  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: DateTimeFormatter itself has numerous static constants like this.

Comment: It is even recommended to store the (immutable) formatter in a static constant (for performance reasons because constructing a formatter can be quite expensive).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Your variable is Thread Safe because it is immutable - No other thread can change it. Other solutions are also possible in your specific case, but I am always in favour of immutable objects.

See [Java Concurrency in practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) Chapter 3. By the way, the chapter seems to be free to browse now, so have a look.

Comment: Chapter 3 not available anymore