# How to parse different ISO date/time formats with Spring MVC @RequestParam

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

Our Rest API is used by several external parties. They all use "ISO-ish" formats, but the formatting of the time zone offset is slightly different. These are some of the most common formats we see:

1. `2018-01-01T15:56:31.410Z`
2. `2018-01-01T15:56:31.41Z`
3. `2018-01-01T15:56:31Z`
4. `2018-01-01T15:56:31+00:00`
5. `2018-01-01T15:56:31+0000`
6. `2018-01-01T15:56:31+00`

In my controller I use the following annotations:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["/some/api/call"], method = [GET])
fun someApiCall(
  @RequestParam("from") 
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) 
  from: OffsetDateTime
) {
  ...
}
```

It parses variant 1-4 just fine but produces a 400 Bad Request error for variants 5 and 6 with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-01-01T13:37:00.001+00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
  at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
```

How can I make it accept all the above ISO formatting variants (even if they are not 100% compliant to the ISO standard)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding a custom formatter annotation:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class IsoDateTime
```

Plus a FormatterFactory:

```
class DefensiveDateTimeFormatterFactory : 
EmbeddedValueResolutionSupport(), AnnotationFormatterFactory<IsoDateTime> 
{
  override fun getParser(annotation: IsoDateTime?, fieldType: Class<*>?): Parser<*> {
    return Parser<OffsetDateTime> { text, _ -> OffsetDateTime.parse(text, JacksonConfig.defensiveFormatter) }
  }

  override fun getPrinter(annotation: IsoDateTime, fieldType: Class<*>): Printer<*> {
    return Printer<OffsetDateTime> { obj, _ -> obj.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME) }
  }

  override fun getFieldTypes(): MutableSet<Class<*>> {
    return mutableSetOf(OffsetDateTime::class.java)
  }
}
```

The actual DateTimeFormat class comes from my other question, [How to parse different ISO date/time formats with Jackson and java.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390734/how-to-parse-different-iso-date-time-formats-with-jackson-and-java-time/49391489?noredirect=1#comment85808586_49391489)

And added it to Spring using WebMvcConfigurer:

```
@Configuration
open class WebMvcConfiguration : WebMvcConfigurer {
  override fun addFormatters(registry: FormatterRegistry) {
    registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(DefensiveDateTimeFormatterFactory())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You get `400-Bad Request` because format 5 and 6 are not part of the `ISO` specifications.

If you look at the Time Zone Designator, it can be one of `Z` or `+hh:mm` or `-hh:mm`.

The official list of  `ISO-8601` formats can be found **[here](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)**.

```
   Year:
      YYYY (eg 1997)
   Year and month:
      YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
   Complete date:
      YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
   Complete date plus hours and minutes:
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)
   Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
   Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a second
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
```

where:

```
     YYYY = four-digit year
     MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
     DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
     hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
     mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
     ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
     s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
     TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
```

Comment: I guess you're right, but nevertheless our clients use these formats (probably they use some broken frameworks/libraries). If possible I would like to accept all formats to give our clients the best possible API experience even if they use broken libraries.

Comment: You may try searching for `@InitBinder`. This way you can supply your own converter mechanism. May be this post might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211323/what-is-the-purpose-of-init-binder-in-spring-mvc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: According to wikipedia, format 6 should be covered by iso8601

Comment: I wouldn't trust a wikipedia page over a `w3.org` published document.

Comment: Me neither, but also W3C is not ISO. The real ISO standard document is not available for free :(